# Creating a dataframe using pandas and random module

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I want to create a dataframe using pandas where 1 column is 'EmployeeID' and the second one is 'skill' set he has ranging form 1 to 5. The 'EmployeeID' column should have unique values whereas the 'skill' column can have repetitive values.
1. I tried to generate  the 'EmployeeID' using the below code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeID':[random.sample(range(123456,135000),100)]})
```

but the result is not what i expected. It generated all the numbers and put them in one row

[image]

2. Random.sample is giving me unique values. How can i generate 100 repetitive values in a given range? Tried using randint but it doesn't have the option of passing the count of numbers to generate

Comment: What is that you expect

Comment: Use `np.random.randint`: `pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeID': np.random.randint(123456, 135000, 100)})`

Comment: Do not use a list since random is already iterable

Comment: Ok. Thats the mistake i was doing by using a list. That clears my first query. How about my second query. Do i have to write a for loop?

Comment: Please try and explain your problem more clearly in future. `How can i generate 100 repetitive values in a given range?` does NOT attempt to explain clearly what your problem is and what you want. Some expected output would also help. Sure, this time there was someone ready to pander to your needs but that won't happen always. Please keep in mind that you are leaving behind a digital carbon footprint for future generations to come across your question should they have the same problem, so don't disappoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) + [`numpy.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) if need repeat `1-5` range:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeID': np.random.randint(123456, 135000, 100),
                   'skill':np.tile(np.arange(1,6), 20)})
print (df.head(10))
   EmployeeID  skill
0      129323      1
1      126570      2
2      124034      3
3      129659      4
4      125654      5
5      127093      1
6      123780      2
7      125665      3
8      124063      4
9      125061      5
```

Also if need random values in range `1-5` for column `skill` use double `randint`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeID': np.random.randint(123456, 135000, 100),
                   'skill':np.random.randint(1,6, 100)})
print (df.head(10))
   EmployeeID  skill
0      131496      2
1      133133      4
2      130999      2
3      127685      5
4      129008      1
5      124238      3
6      124147      3
7      123592      3
8      133859      1
9      126097      3
```